# How can I prevent a ssh login failing from occurring if a script run via pam_exec.so fails?

Tags: ssh, pam

I'm trying to trigger a script everytime a login occurs over SSH. I've added the following line to the end of `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session    required pam_exec.so stdout /home/root/xyz/login-alert.sh
```

However, my concern now is, **if the script fails** for some reason - that seems to prevent the login of the user.

How can I prevent a login not occurring due to the above? Do I just wrap it in a second bash script `/home/root/xyz/login-alert.sh || true` - though I'm not sure if this covers all possible cases.

Answer (score 2):

Seems I just need to change `required` to `optional` according to:

http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-configuration-file.html

> optional
>
> the success or failure of this module is only important if it is the only module in the stack associated with this service+type.